How to properly drag an image overlay in leaflet?
I am currently trying to build a website using leaflet that allows the dragging of image overlays. I feel so close to getting it right, but for some reason, whenever I zoom in or out the image returns to its original position. I have tried a lot, but whatever I do seems to make it worse at this point lol. Here is the JS code I currently have:
// Function to convert kilometers to latitude/longitude changes
function kilometersToLatLon(kilometers, latitude) {
    var latChange = kilometers / 111.0;
    var lonChange = kilometers / (111.0 * Math.cos(latitude * Math.PI / 180));
    return { latChange: latChange, lonChange: lonChange };
}

// Define the center coordinates (Charleston, SC)
var centerLat = 32.7765;
var centerLon = -79.9311;

// Define image width and height in kilometers
var widthInKilometers = 9.1070;
var heightInKilometers = 8.6625;

// Convert kilometers to latitude and longitude changes
var latLonWidth = kilometersToLatLon(widthInKilometers, centerLat);
var latLonHeight = kilometersToLatLon(heightInKilometers, centerLat);

// Calculate top-left and bottom-right coordinates based on width and height
var topLeftLat = centerLat - latLonHeight.latChange / 2;
var topLeftLon = centerLon - latLonWidth.lonChange / 2;
var bottomRightLat = centerLat + latLonHeight.latChange / 2;
var bottomRightLon = centerLon + latLonWidth.lonChange / 2;

// Path to the image hosted on your local server (Live Server)
var imageUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/Images/overlay.png';

// Add the image overlay
var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, [[topLeftLat, topLeftLon], [bottomRightLat, bottomRightLon]], {
    opacity: 0.8,
    interactive: true
}).addTo(map);

// Make the ImageOverlay draggable
let imgElement = imageOverlay.getElement();
let draggable = new L.Draggable(imgElement);

// Enable the draggable functionality
draggable.enable();

// Initialize draggable and set the image overlay position relative to the map
draggable.on('dragstart', () => {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();  // Disable zoom on the map
});

// Re-enable zoom on the map when dragging ends
draggable.on('dragend', () => {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();   // Re-enable zoom on the map
});

// Update the overlay bounds as it is dragged
draggable.on('drag', () => {
    const imgPos = L.DomUtil.getPosition(imgElement);
    const topLeft = map.containerPointToLatLng(imgPos);
    const bottomRight = map.containerPointToLatLng({
            x: imgPos.x + imgElement.offsetWidth,
            y: imgPos.y + imgElement.offsetHeight,
    });

    imageOverlay.setBounds([topLeft, bottomRight]);
});

// Remove the draggable instance on map move and re-create it
map.on('moveend', () => {
    // Disable the current draggable instance
    draggable.disable();

    // Recreate the draggable instance after map move ends
    draggable = new L.Draggable(imgElement);
    draggable.enable(); // Re-enable dragging functionality
});

I have tried a lot of stuff for hours that awlays makes the code messy. Often times, I manage to prevent the issue, but by creating a bigger issue where, if I click on the image to drag it, it gets offset from the mouse corresponding to the offset between my original and current camera position.

Please show the code for how you are placing the images
